# Parallelize & accelerate loops of tensor additions

Tags: python, pytorch, parallel-processing, gpu, tensor

**Background:**

I am working on a program that first shifts the different channels of a tensor along the "column" dimension with different distances, and then performs a summation along the "channel" dimension to merge the different dimensions into one. Specifically, given a tensor x of size (B,C,H,W) and step size S, where B, C, H, W represent the batch size, channel number, height, and width, respectively, the i-th channel of x is shifted by distance (i-1)*S, and then the C channels are summed into one.

Here is an 1D toy example.
Assume that I have a 3-channel tensor x as

```py
x = torch.tensor(
[[1,1,1],
[2,2,2],
[3,3,3]]
)
```

Now I set the step size as 1, and then perform a shift on the tensor as

```py
x_shifted = torch.tensor(
[[1,1,1,0,0],
[0,2,2,2,0],
[0,0,3,3,3]]
)
```

Here, the first channel is shifted by distance 0, the second channel is shifted by distance 1, and the third channel is shifted by distance 2.
Finally, all the three channels are summed and merged into one as

```py
y = torch.tensor(
[[1,3,6,5,3]]
)
```

---

**Question:**

I have implemented the original process w.r.t. 2D image tensors in the following code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from time import time

#############################################
# Parameters
#############################################

B = 16
C = 28
H = 256
W = 256
S = 2
T = 1000
device = torch.device('cuda')

seed = 2023
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

#############################################
# Method 1
#############################################

alpha = torch.zeros(B, 1, 1, W+(C-1)*S, device=device)
for i in range(C):
    alpha[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] += 1

def A(x, mask):
    z = x * mask
    y = torch.zeros(B, 1, H, W+(C-1)*S, device=x.device)
    for i in range(C):
        y[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] += z[:, (i):(i+1)]
    return y

def A_pinv(y, mask):
    z = y / alpha.to(y.device)
    x = torch.cat([z[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] for i in range(C)], dim=1) / mask
    return x

#############################################
# Method 2
#############################################

kernel = torch.zeros(1, C, 1, (C-1)*S+1, device=device)
for i in range(C):
    kernel[:, C-i-1, :, i*S] = 1

def A_fast(x, mask):
    return F.conv2d(x * mask, kernel.to(x.device), padding=(0, (C-1)*S))

def A_pinv_fast(y, mask):
    return F.conv_transpose2d(y / alpha.to(y.device), kernel, padding=(0, (C-1)*S)) / mask

#############################################
# Test 1
#############################################
start_time = time()
MAE = 0
for i in range(T):
    x = torch.rand(B, C, H, W, device=device)
    mask = torch.rand(1, 1, H, W, device=device)
    mask[mask == 0] = 1e-12
    y = A(x, mask)
    x_init = A_pinv(y, mask)
    y_init = A(x_init, mask)
    MAE += (y_init - y).abs().mean().item()
MAE /= T
end_time = time()
print('---')
print('Test 1')
print('Running Time:', end_time - start_time)
print('MAE:', MAE)

#############################################
# Test 2
#############################################
start_time = time()
MAE = 0
for i in range(T):
    x = torch.rand(B, C, H, W, device=device)
    mask = torch.rand(1, 1, H, W, device=device)
    mask[mask == 0] = 1e-12
    y = A_fast(x, mask)
    x_init = A_pinv_fast(y, mask)
    y_init = A_fast(x_init, mask)
    MAE += (y_init - y).abs().mean().item()
MAE /= T
end_time = time()
print('---')
print('Test 2')
print('Running Time:', end_time - start_time)
print('MAE:', MAE)
```

Here, `Method 1` implements the process with a `for` loop, while I believe that `Method 2` implements the process equivalently by using a 2D convolution operation.

To be more specific, functions `A` and `A_pinv` realize the forwarding compress process and its "pseudo-inverse", respectively. Their "fast" versions in `Method 2` are expected to be faster with a parallelized implementation.

**However,** when I run the code, I find that the `Method 1` is still much faster than the `Method 2` with large speed leading. I want to ask that:

Can we effectively accelerate the `Method 1`? To be more specific, I wonder if we can parallelize the `for` loops, to make the "Shift+Summation" process faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Large-kernel convolutions are not necessarily efficient.
[`torch.scatter_add_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_add_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_add_) can sum over the shifted elements directly.

I didn't write the pseudo inverse (I think it was to check for correctness? I compared this new method with your Method1/Method2).

```py
out_W = W + (C-1)*S
i_list = torch.arange(C, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
y_list = torch.arange(H, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
x_list = torch.arange(W, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
indices = x_list + i_list.view(C, 1, 1)*S + y_list.view(1, H, 1)*(out_W)
indices = indices.view(1, C*H*W).expand(B, C*H*W)
"""
functionally equivalent to:
for i in range(C):
    for y in range(H):
        for x in range(W):
            indices[i*H*W+y*W+x] = x + i*S + y*(out_W)
"""

def A_faster(x, mask):
    y = torch.zeros(B, H*out_W, device=x.device)
    y.scatter_add_(1, indices, (x*mask).view(B, C*H*W))
    return y.view(B, 1, H, out_W)
```

Surprisingly, your method 1 holds up well even for larger `C` (or scatter does not scale well).

For `C=28`:

```
---   
Test 1                          
Running Time: 1.4626126289367676  
---                                                                                                      
Test 2                   
Running Time: 2.808514356613159                                                                          
---                                                                                                      
Test 3                                                                                                   
Running Time: 1.3663663864135742                
---                                                                                                      
|Test1 - Test2|:  tensor(9.2172e-07, device='cuda:0')
---   
|Test1 - Test3|:  tensor(7.5425e-09, device='cuda:0')
---                               
|Test2 - Test3|:  tensor(9.2173e-07, device='cuda:0')
```

For `C=512` (method 2 skipped as it is too slow):

```
---
Test 1
Running Time: 27.37247085571289
---
Test 3
Running Time: 24.335933446884155
---
|Test1 - Test3|:  tensor(3.9411e-08, device='cuda:0')
```

Full testing code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from time import time

#############################################
# Parameters
#############################################

B = 16
C = 28
H = 256
W = 256
S = 2
T = 1000
device = torch.device('cuda')

seed = 2023
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

#############################################
# Method 1
#############################################

alpha = torch.zeros(B, 1, 1, W+(C-1)*S, device=device)
for i in range(C):
    alpha[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] += 1

def A(x, mask):
    z = x * mask
    y = torch.zeros(B, 1, H, W+(C-1)*S, device=x.device)
    for i in range(C):
        y[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] += z[:, (i):(i+1)]
    return y

def A_pinv(y, mask):
    z = y / alpha.to(y.device)
    x = torch.cat([z[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] for i in range(C)], dim=1) / mask
    return x

#############################################
# Method 2
#############################################

kernel = torch.zeros(1, C, 1, (C-1)*S+1, device=device)
for i in range(C):
    kernel[:, C-i-1, :, i*S] = 1

def A_fast(x, mask):
    return F.conv2d(x * mask, kernel.to(x.device), padding=(0, (C-1)*S))

def A_pinv_fast(y, mask):
    return F.conv_transpose2d(y / alpha.to(y.device), kernel, padding=(0, (C-1)*S)) / mask


#############################################
# Method 3
#############################################
out_W = W + (C-1)*S
i_list = torch.arange(C, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
y_list = torch.arange(H, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
x_list = torch.arange(W, dtype=torch.long, device=device)
indices = x_list + i_list.view(C, 1, 1)*S + y_list.view(1, H, 1)*(out_W)
indices = indices.view(1, C*H*W).expand(B, C*H*W)
"""
functionally equivalent to:
for i in range(C):
    for y in range(H):
        for x in range(W):
            indices[i*H*W+y*W+x] = x + i*S + y*(out_W)
"""

def A_faster(x, mask):
    y = torch.zeros(B, H*out_W, device=x.device)
    y.scatter_add_(1, indices, (x*mask).view(B, C*H*W))
    return y.view(B, 1, H, out_W)


#############################################
# Test 1
#############################################
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_time = time()
for i in range(T):
    x = torch.rand(B, C, H, W, device=device)
    mask = torch.rand(1, 1, H, W, device=device)
    mask[mask == 0] = 1e-12
    y = A(x, mask)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_time = time()
print('---')
print('Test 1')
print('Running Time:', end_time - start_time)

#############################################
# Test 2
#############################################
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_time = time()
for i in range(T):
    x = torch.rand(B, C, H, W, device=device)
    mask = torch.rand(1, 1, H, W, device=device)
    mask[mask == 0] = 1e-12
    y = A_fast(x, mask)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_time = time()
print('---')
print('Test 2')
print('Running Time:', end_time - start_time)

#############################################
# Test 3
#############################################
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start_time = time()
for i in range(T):
    x = torch.rand(B, C, H, W, device=device)
    mask = torch.rand(1, 1, H, W, device=device)
    mask[mask == 0] = 1e-12
    y = A_faster(x, mask)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end_time = time()
print('---')
print('Test 3')
print('Running Time:', end_time - start_time)


error = 0
for _ in range(T):
    error += (A(x, mask) - A_fast(x, mask)).abs().mean()
error /= T
print('---')
print('|Test1 - Test2|: ', error)

error = 0
for _ in range(T):
    error += (A(x, mask) - A_faster(x, mask)).abs().mean()
error /= T
print('---')
print('|Test1 - Test3|: ', error)

error = 0
for _ in range(T):
    error += (A_fast(x, mask) - A_faster(x, mask)).abs().mean()
error /= T
print('---')
print('|Test2 - Test3|: ', error)
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach for you to accelerate the "**Shift+Summation**" process in '**Method 1**' is by parallelizing the for loops. In your case, you can use **PyTorch's built-in parallel processing features** to achieve this, by utilizing the '**torch.nn.parallel.data_parallel**' function. This function parallelizes the computation across multiple GPUs or CPU cores.

```
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn.parallel import data_parallel
from time import time

#############################################
# Parameters
#############################################

B = 16
C = 28
H = 256
W = 256
S = 2
T = 1000
device = torch.device('cuda')

seed = 2023
torch.manual_seed(seed)
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(seed)

#############################################
# Method 1 Edited***
#############################################

alpha = torch.zeros(B, 1, 1, W+(C-1)*S, device=device)
for i in range(C):
    alpha[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] += 1

def A(x, mask): # Edited From Here.
    z = x * mask
    y = torch.zeros(B, 1, H, W+(C-1)*S, device=x.device)
    
    def process_channel(i):
        y[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] += z[:, (i):(i+1)]
        
    data_parallel(process_channel, range(C))
    
    return y

def A_pinv(y, mask):
    z = y / alpha.to(y.device)
    x = torch.cat([z[..., (i*S):(i*S+W)] for i in range(C)], dim=1) / mask
    return x # End here.
```

By using the data_parallel function, the for loop in the '**A**' function will be automatically parallelized across the available devices, leading to faster execution. The benefits of parallelization will be more explicity if you have multiple GPUs. (Which GPU are you using it?)

You can learn more about this topic in the official documentation: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html (*It's the last item on the page*).

Comment: Hi @f05135, thank you very much! I have only one GPU. Can I enjoy the parallelization?

Comment: When I run the code, I receive the following message: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\chenbin\Desktop\test.py", line 91, in <module>
    y = A_fast(x, mask)
  File "c:\Users\chenbin\Desktop\test.py", line 51, in A_fast
    data_parallel(f, range(C))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\parallel\data_parallel.py", line 214, in data_parallel
    for t in chain(module.parameters(), module.buffers()):
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'parameters'